# listtransactions via RPC returns false in PHP

Tags: json-rpc, php

In PHP I run

```
$bitcoin->listtransactions("count = 5, offset = 0");
```

In the hope of getting 5 transactions only, but I get the response

```
bool(false)
```

When I run $bitcoin->listtransactions(); alone, it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't offer money for solving your problem - it's fine to give people money after the fact, but not to advertise it in advance. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, there are several optional parameters you can provide  in order to retrieve list of transactions for account(s).

Function:

```
listtransactions [account] [count=10] [skip=0] [include_watch_only]
```

1. `[account]` (string) leave `""` for default account and `"*"` for all accounts, default `""`
2. `[count]` (int) number of recent tx to return, default is `10`
3. `[skip]` (int) number of recent tx not to return, default is `0`
4. `[include_watch_only]` (bool) include watch-only addresses, default is `false`

I suggest to try the call with all 4 parameters:

```
$bitcoin->listtransactions("*", 10, 0, false);
```

I am not PHP expert but the output you get might be indication of missing parameters.

Comment: None of those parameters are required - but passing in the first parameter like that tells bitcoin that you want all transactions from the account named `count = 5, offset = 0`.